# List Rarible Lazy Minted Tokens on OpenSea

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, nft, opensea, lazy-minting

How can I list Rarible Lazy Minted off-chain tokens on OpenSea?

I am Lazy Minting tokens on Rarible that go to a custom smart contract during the sale. Before the sale, the tokens are stored off-chain but still listed on Rarible. How do I get these off-chain tokens to also be listed on OpenSea?

In other words, I need to list off-chain lazy minted tokens on Rarible and OpenSea that mint to a custom smart contract at sale.